# Generate unique ID using customer information

Tags: java, hash, uuid

I am trying to design a system in which user should be unique across different instances.

I have:

- first name
- last name
- email

I want to generate a **unique ID** using these three fields so that the ID can be used to find out if the customer is same. Also, the system should generate the same ID if the combination is repeated.

Any suggestions? what could be a good approach in Java.

Comment: What type should your id have? If `String` is sufficient, [@xtractic's answer looks feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49678866/4216641). Another way would be to let a database handle IDs (provided, you use a database). If you are forced to use some numeric value as id, you cannot guarantee uniqueness of IDs.

Answer (score 4):

Full email should be unique already, so email alone should be good.

If you want to include all then you must be sure that all fields will be included across all instances and concatenate them with some pattern (multiple characters if desired) that will not occur within the fields.

So long as the fields are always separated by this pattern and no user will have the same fields (for all of them) then these ids will always be unique and recreatable.

Eg: `email-firstname-lastname`

**NOTE:**

You should be sure that the delimiter will not occur in the fields. Otherwise the fields can bleed into each other.

`firstname="billy-bob", lastname="joe"` `->` `email-billy-bob-joe`

would have the same id as

`firstname="billy", lastname="bob-joe"` `->` `email-billy-bob-joe`

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate fName, lName and email and use `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(concat.getBytes()).toString()`

Example:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class asd {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fName = "fName";
    String lName = "lName";
    String email = "email@gmail.com";
    String concat = fName+lName+email;
    String result = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(concat.getBytes()).toString();
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: an important thing to note is if someone is `fName="foo", lName="bar", email="baz@x.com"` then their id by this method would be equivalent to someone `fName="foo", lName="ba", email="rbaz@x.com"`.. use unique delimiters that will not occur in the fields.

Comment: also UUID is not guaranteed to be unique (despite the name)  for any given fields, it's just highly likely to be unique, but if OP requires a guaranteed unique then I am against UUID. Eg it's possible that the UUID from `fName="A",  lName="B", email="C"` could possibly (although unlikely) be equivalent to `fName="X",  lName="Y", email="Z"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use any hash-function (like SHA-1, MD-5 and so on) to produce fixed-size hash as user id from first name, last name and email. I would recommend to make one string from all attributes with some delimiter before calculating hash. And probably to normalize resulted string to upper/lower case is good choice. F.e.

```
        String delimiter = ..;
        String email = ..;
        String firstName = ..;
        String lastName = ..;
        String data = email + delimiter + firstName + delimiter + lastName;
        String userId = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(data.toLowerCase());
```

For hash calculation I took [Apache Commons Codec](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec) in this example.

Comment: Hash is a wrong good idea as you may have collisions. I didn't downvote. See the xtratic that answer addresses more finely  the question.

Comment: as has already been pointed out on other answers to this question. Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique.. how could they be when they are a limited size but their inputs are (essentially) not limited?

Comment: Last SHA-1 collision attack made by Google price ~100K $. What collision are you talking about?

Comment: @Yuriy Alevohin https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html Anyway the computation is expensive. I am not sure that it makes sense to use such a algorithm.

Comment: It's almost impossible to have random collision for SHA-1 or any modern hash function. Plus - id is rather small and fixed sized.

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin thing is... most collisions are not "random" ;)

Comment: Usually when someone needs something to be unique it must be guaranteed. Hashes introduce uncertainty that user X and user Y could end up with the same hash and thus same id.